# Implementing deep link in react native

Tags: ios, react-native

I’m Implementing deep link in react native app to click on View in app A to open app B. Before calling URL directly from another app I wanted to test it if it is working or not,

So for android it worked. I just set the launch option to URL and it showed the value of URL in console.

But in iPhone if I write the URL(***testlink://***) in safari browser it shows “safari cannot open the page because address is invalid”.

Steps I followed to setup deeplinking:

1. Added following code in AppDelgate.m

```js
    #import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>
    
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
      sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
    {
      return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url
                          sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
    }
    
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity
     restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray * _Nullable))restorationHandler
    {
     return [RCTLinkingManager application:application
                      continueUserActivity:userActivity
                        restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
    }
```

2. Added a key in info.plist in XCode.

   > URLTypes -> Item 0 -> URL identifier(VALUE: testlink)
3. Adding the following code in Home page of the App.

```js
   

 componentDidMount() {
      Linking.addEventListener('url', this._handleOpenURL);
    },
    componentWillUnmount() {
      Linking.removeEventListener('url', this._handleOpenURL);
    },
    _handleOpenURL(event) {
      console.log(event.url);
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you added `testlink://` as a URL type in XCode?

For the purpose of this example, my Bundle Identifier is: `org.reactjs.native.example.MyApp`

1. Click on your project in Xcode, and click on the `Info` tab
2. Scroll down to `URL Types`
3. Click the + button
4. Add the Identifier: `org.reactjs.native.example.MyApp.linking`
5. Add URL Schemes: `testlink`
6. Clean & Build
7. Open Safari and type in `testlink://` - it should open your app.

Comment: Thank you it worked but now I'm facing a weird issue if the app is already open it shows the black screen. Any suggestions?

Comment: If the app is already open from URL then it shows the black screen on calling the URL again otherwise it works fine.